# Variance of prediction--linear regression

Tags: regression, prediction

Let's say you have a regression model and then predict a new y at a specific x. How would I find the variance of this prediction?

Comment: Prediction interval? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval

Comment: do you have a specific regression model in mind (linear regression, Generalized Linear Model, Gaussian Process regression, etc.) or are you asking a completely general question?

Comment: There are many, many ways to do this and many, many "regression models" out there.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22prediction+interval%22+regression for some solutions.